# Dynamic Checkboxes getting reset?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, fullcalendar

I have a fullcalendar displayed and a list of resources with checkboxes displayed next to their name. They checkboxes show up correctly and if i dont do anything with them they stay checked like they normally would. But, when i call fullcalendar with jquery and go to add or remove a resource, the checkboxes uncheck themselves after running the jquery/fullcalendar functions.

here is how i create the checkboxes:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

for(p in dsnrs){
            $('#specialists').append(
            '<input type="checkbox" name="designer" id="' + dsnrs[p].name +'" onChange="addOrRem(dsnrs['+p+'] )" />' +dsnrs[p].name+ '<br />');
        }
});
```

And here are my functions for adding/removing the calendar resources

```
function addOrRem(spec){
    //alert("Specialist: " + spec.name + ", Checked: " +document.getElementById(spec.name).checked);
    if(document.getElementById(spec.name).checked==true){
        remRes(spec.id);
        addRes(spec);
    }if(document.getElementById(spec.name).checked=false){
        remRes(spec.id);
    }
}
function addRes(spec) {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'addEventResource', spec );
}

function remRes(id) {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'removeEventResource', id);
}
```

Here is the relevant HTML

```
<div id='designersbox' style='float:left;margin-top:5px'>
   <div id='specialists' onload='specList()'></div>
    <a href="#" onClick="addRes()">Add resource</a>
    <a href="#" onClick="remRes()">Remove resource</a>
</div>
<div id='calbox' style="width:1000px;height:900px;position:relative;float:left;margin-bottom:10px; padding:10px">
    <div id='calendar' style="float:left;height:1000px;width:1000px;"></div>
</div>
```

I'm not really sure why the checkboxes are getting reset. If i comment out the calls to the add/remove functions and just do the alert, they work fine. Any help or clues would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

added a var, checked = document.getElementById(spec.name).checked;

Seemed to fix the problem. I'm not sure why it works, but replacing the if statements with checked==true/false instead of not using the variable fixed the issue.

new function:

```
function addOrRem(spec){
    //$(":checkbox[value=designer]").attr("checked", true);
    //alert("Specialist: " + spec.name + ", Checked: " +document.getElementById(spec.name).checked);
    var checked = document.getElementById(spec.name).checked;
    if(checked==true){
        remRes(spec.id, '#calendard');
        addRes(spec, '#calendard') ;
    }if(checked==false){
        remRes(spec.id, '#calendard');
    }
}
```